# How to disable user login on GCP App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

My flask application is deployed to App Engine and it seems to be functional and we are able to view it fine. We want to share the application with some HR folks for trying it out, but they are unable to view it - it is asking them to select a google account. Is there a way to disable this or remove user login so that those without GCP access can view the app?

Comment: What type of authentication did you put into your code? Review this link: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/oauth/

Comment: I don't know - I didn't set up app engine. Is there a way to reconfigure for certain instances?

Comment: The link will show you details. Did you read it and follow the links for your configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that your app engine is protected by IAP. For checking this, go to Security -> Identity Aware Proxy. You should have this page:

[image]

With the IAP slider in green to the right. For allowing the unauthenticated users on your service, you have to select your AppEngine service name, go to the right panel, click on AddMember. Now select `allUsers` and add the role `IAP web app user`

[image]

And save. If you want to allow on some Google accounts and/or user groups, do the same thing but not on allUsers but with the appropriate email accounts.

**HOWEVER**, if the IAP has been activate on the project, it's for a good reason. Be sure that you do not enforce your company policy by doing this. You also have to be authorized to perform this operation, all depends of your roles on the project.